# realurl 2.x, how to get empty url for homepage as in realurl 1.x (SEO)

Tags: seo, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, typo3-7.x

I have a TYPO3 7.6.5 installation that requires realurl 2.x ... Until now I used TYPO3 6.2.x and realurl 1.x. The rootpage of the website in my pagetree is NOT my homepage, instead the rootpage is a shortcut to a page further down the tree. Until now i was able to write a '/' in the realurl pathsegment field to have the homepage show up as http://www.somedomain.tld/ instead of http://www.somedomain.tld/home.html (better for SEO) ... with 2.x this does no longer work. Does anyone know why or how to achieve the same behaviour?

Thanks